# Visual Studio C#: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service, windows-7, windows-services

I have created a service which performs many checks against one database and updates another with the results of the checks.
However, I get the subject error every time I try to start the service.
I am able to successfully run the service in the debugger and everything works fine.
I have also adjusted the timeout as described here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344 to no avail.
Below is my Program.cs file:

```
    namespace PlantMonitor
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
#if (!DEBUG)
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#else
            var service = new Service1();
            service.StartUp();  //Make the method public in order to Debug
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Service1.cs file:

```
namespace PlantMonitor
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        //declare the SetServiceStatus function by using platform invoke
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
.
.
.
 public void StartUp()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }


        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //startup stuff

            // Update the service state to Start Pending.
            ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
            serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 180000;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
            //ConnectionState
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");



            // Set up a timer to trigger every minute.

            timer.Interval = 10000; // 10 seconds
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
            timer.Start();

            //Confrim Timer success
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Timer Success");

            // Update the service state to Running.
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
        }
```

Basically, I set the timer to 10 seconds initially to begin the first iteration of the main code contained in OnTimer and adjust the timer.Interval to 3 min once I step inside OnTimer.
When I try to start the service I can see that it reports events to the log file that exist within the OnTimer method.

This is my first attempt at writing a service, but I would have expected the service to be considered "running" once it hits this line of code:

```
// Update the service state to Running.
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
```

When I run it in the debugger, it always reaches this line of code prior to firing OnTimer. Am I not updating the service state correctly?

**[EDIT]** Upon review of the event log, it appears that the service continues to run through the OnTimer event, even after the Service Manager throws the subject error. However, once it completes the OnTimer method once, the service is stopped.

Comment: You should not need to do anything with the service state manually. `ServiceBase.Run` should be handling all that for you.

Comment: I removed the manual service state updates and call ServiceBase.Run in the Main method, but this does not resolve the problem.         `public static void Main()
        {
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new Service1());
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to take care of updating the service state - while you are inside `OnStart(...)` the service state is start pending, when you exit the method, it's state will change to running. I never tried to update the service state manually <s>but I think this causes the method to hang around until it times out.</s>
Edit: It seems the main() as part of the Project caused a wrong entry registererd for the Service.

Comment: I commented out the sections where I updated the service status, but this did not resolve the problem. I manually updated the status based on the MSDN walkthrough (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is your main() part of the same project? Maybe this causes the issue. Try to create a windows service application with the wizard from scratch a put your existing code into OnStart. I have no idea what else could cause the problem, the other code should not cause this trouble.

Comment: Thanks. Recreating the project seems to have worked.